# Securing/Encrypting the sensitive environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using an env file which contains sensitive information for docker creation.

But the thing is they are not secure. They can be easily viewed via docker inspect, and hence they are available to any user that can run docker commands.

I'm looking for a way in which I can secure these values from the outside users, without using docker swarm.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need them on built-time or also on container-run-time?

Comment: @mulg0r I need some on built-time and some on container-run-time

Comment: On built time you can use `--build-arg` or `ARG` inside Dockerfile

Comment: @mulg0r what about run time?

Comment: I'll write it down

Answer (score 2):

For variables needed in built-time (image creation):

- ARG: --build-arg

For env variables needed when container starts:

- --env-file: It lets you nobody can see your variables doing `history` inspecting your cli command.
- Use docker secrets: possible in swarm, docker enterprise. ([docker swarm secrets)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)